# Calcular valor delta para assertEquals em JUnit

Tags: java, junit

Saudações.

Qual a melhor forma de calcular o valor delta do método assertEquals(message, expected, actual, delta) do JUnit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O propósito do parâmetro `delta` [desse método](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.String,%20double,%20double,%20double)) é **determinar o valor máximo da diferença entre os números `expected` e `actual` para que eles sejam considerados o mesmo valor**.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que você tem uma rotina que retorna um número de ponto flutuante `double`. Você espera o valor `2.5`, mas a rotina retorna `2.499999999999`.

Esses problemas com precisão podem ocorrer pelo conhecido dilema da representação numérica usando bits, portanto é esperado que numa sequência de operações numéricas ocorra uma perda de precisão.

Outra fonte desta diferença podem ser arredondamentos feitos durante os cálculos.

Na maioria dos casos você pode tolerar essas pequenas diferenças, principalmente quando os resultados não são usados como entrada para outros processos e as casas decimais são pouco relevantes.

Então, basicamente você precisa determinar quantas casas decimais importam no contexto do seu sistema. Por exemplo, um sistema financeiro pessoal pode tolerar falhas de cálculo a partir da terceira casa decimal, pois no Real a precisão é dada em centavos. Entretanto, em instituições financeiras ou alguns tipos de negócios (como postos de gasolina) podem precisar de maior precisão, usando 3 ou 4 casas dependendo do cálculo.

Então, por exemplo, se você passar um valor de delta de `0.01`, o JUnit vai lançar um erro se `abs(expected - actual) > 0.01`.

Em geral, para sistemas financeiros, essa precisão deve estar especificada em algum lugar, pois é peça central dos negócios.

No entanto, eu não recomendaria depender desse tipo de cálculo de precisão quando em muitos casos é possível contornar isso.

Primeiro, veja se o uso de `double` é necessário. Muita gente usa essas variáveis sem pensar quando os valores na verdade poderiam ser inteiros como `int` ou `long`.

Segundo, para cálculos onde a precisão é importante, pense em usar `BigDecimal`, que embora seja mais lento não sofre dos problemas de representação binária.

Comment: Sua resposta foi excelente. Obrigado.